# Create XML from JQuery with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, xml

How is this done to generate an XML file based on this data?

```
$("#savequiz").click(function(){
    var text = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><quiz>";
    // save the general settings
    text += "<title><![CDATA[" + $('input[name="title"]').val() + "]]></title>";
    text += "<time><![CDATA[" + $('input[name="time"]').val() + "]]></time>";

    text += "<singlechoice><![CDATA[" + $('input[name="singlechoice"]').val() + "]]></singlechoice>";
    text += "<multiplechoice><![CDATA[" + $('input[name="multiplechoice"]').val() + "]]></multiplechoice>";
    text += "<nextbutton><![CDATA[" + $('input[name="nextbutton"]').val() + "]]></nextbutton>";
    text += "<prevbutton><![CDATA[" + $('input[name="prevbutton"]').val() + "]]></prevbutton>";
    text += "<finishbutton><![CDATA[" + $('input[name="finishbutton"]').val() + "]]></finishbutton>";
    text += "<startbutton><![CDATA[" + $('input[name="startbutton"]').val() + "]]></startbutton>";
    text += "<reviewbutton><![CDATA[" + $('input[name="reviewbutton"]').val() + "]]></reviewbutton>";
    text += "<resultscreentitle><![CDATA[" + $('input[name="resultscreentitle"]').val() + "]]></resultscreentitle>";
    text += "<resultscreenresultline><![CDATA[" + $('input[name="resultscreenresultline"]').val() + "]]></resultscreenresultline>";
    text += "<welcometext><![CDATA[" + $('textarea[name="welcometext"]').val() + "]]></welcometext>";
    for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        var q = questions[i];
        var answers = q.getAnswers();
        text += "<question><![CDATA[" + q.getQuestion() + "]]>"; 
        for(var n = 0; n < answers.length; n++){
            text += "<answer correct='" + answers[n].getCorrect() + "'>";
            text += "<![CDATA[" + answers[n].getAnswer() + "]]></answer>";  
        };
        text +="</question>";
    };
    text +="</quiz>";

    // save to file:
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "savequiz.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "filename=" + filename + ".xml" + "&quiz=" + text,
        success: function (text) {
            //console.log(text.errors);
            //console.log(text.feedback);
            if(text.feedback == "saved") respondChangedState(false);
        }
    });
```

How will the PHP file look like to be able to retrive the information and then save it to a file in the same folder?

Comment: why not pass the info by `JSON` then on the php file, create the file structure with the information passed?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST);` in your `savequiz.php` and take it from there.

Comment: Okey, I'm quite new to JSON and PHP so I'm not quite sure how its done..

Answer (score 1):

Keep tranfering data as small as possible to increase performance; I suggest you to do it like:

JS:

```
//passin data via ajax
 ...
url: "savequiz.php",
data:{
   title : $(input[name="title"]).val(),
   name : $(input[name="name"]).val(),
   //and so on ...
}
```

savequiz.php :

```
 $title = $_POST['title'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 //and so on ...

 //and HERE is the proper place to create XML file using above $_POST data
 //and save it to a folder.
```

and try do more research to know how to [create XML file](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-XML-Creating-XML-Document-P413.html) and [Working with files](http://phpmaster.com/working-with-files-in-php/) using PHP.